# Lotus Notes: RichText Content

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

I want to create a field that will tell me,
if that field's content is empty (ex: no attachment),
it will reflect in another field that it is empty.

For that reason,
I have created/tested a Rich-Text field in a form.
Let's say that Rich-Text Name is Test1.

Then, I added a computed text field, let's say the name is Test2.

[image]

In Test2 field, I set the formula as this,

@If(Test1!="";"Yes";"No")

As a result, in the Test2's field, it does not show me that the Test1's field is empty, even though it has no text/attachment inside the Test1 field.

[image]

I have tested many times, and the result is still the same.

Please help me on this matter to solve this problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: RichTextFields are odd ducks.  You can't usually treat them like regular text fields.  You can use @Text() to convert it to text, but that loses attachments.  You can use @Attachments() but attachments may not be in that (or any) RTF.  Either of those scenarios may be acceptable in your case, but that would be up to you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct solution AFAIK. If using LotusScript is an option for you, here's a common workaround to find out whether an RT field is empty:

- Put the focus on the RT field by calling NotesUiDocument.GoToField("Test1").
- Select all contents of the RT field by calling NotesUiDocument.SelectAll().

The call to NotesUiDocument.SelectAll will raise an error (can't remember wich error code) if the RT field is empty. Trap that error using On Error GoTo <label of error handler>. If the code does not enter the error handler, you know the RT field is not empty. If it does, you know the RT field is empty. You can then take the appropriate action, e.g. put a message in text field 'Test2'.

To make this approach more user-friendly, I'd also suggest you add some code that puts the focus back on the original field (i.e., the field that had the focus before the above LS code was triggered).